# I need to store all colors of imageview inside a linkedlist but its not working

Tags: java, android, linked-list, imageview

Hi  as title mentions I want to go row by row and store all colors of an image in my imageview  in a linked list since I dont know the size. but it keeps saying x must be >0 or y must be >0 and I googled it and fixed it but still the error persists.

at first I tried on touch but then commented it to try on click

with on touch I could get color of each place I touch but storing it still gives me the error.

```
public class Encrypt extends Activity {

private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE=1;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_encode);
    Button open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final Button openGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    openGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);

        }
    });



}

View.OnClickListener onClick1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        iv.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();



        int pixel_old = 0;
        int pixel_new = 0;
        int count = 0;


        LinkedList<String> colors_list = new LinkedList<>();


        //txt.setText( " h: " + color);

        for (int i=iv.getMinimumHeight(); i< iv.getMaxHeight();i++){
            for(int j=iv.getMinimumWidth(); j<iv.getMaxWidth();j++){
                pixel_new= bitmap.getPixel(i,j);
                if(pixel_new != pixel_old){
                    colors_list.add(String.format("%06X",0xFFFFFF & pixel_new));
                    count =0;
                }
                else {

                }
                pixel_old=pixel_new;

            }
        }
        txt.setText(colors_list.get(1)+"   "+colors_list.get(2));

    }
};
/*
   OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
        = new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        iv.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();


        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        String color = String.format("%06X",0xFFFFFF & pixel);






        txt.setText("p: "+pixel+" h: "+color);

        return true;
    }};
    */


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECTED_PICTURE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri=data.getData();
                String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                String filePath=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap yourSelectedImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);

                iv.setBackground(d);
               // iv.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
                iv.setOnClickListener(onClick1);

            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }



}
```

Comment: post your error stack

Answer (score 0):

The `getDrawingCache()` will return a bitmap of the entire `View` including borders and padding, if you want to get the colors of the image that the `ImageView` is using, try this:

```
Bitmap  b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int x = 0; x < b.getWidth(); x++){
   for(int y = 0;y < b.getHeight(); y++){
      colors.add(String.format("%06X",0xFFFFFF & b.getPixel(x,y)));
   }
}
```

Also, the `getPixel(...)` method accepts 2 `int` parameters, the first one is the x coordinate and the second one is the y coordinate, you are reversing this coordinates in your code because `i` is the y coordinate.

Comment: I tried your solution with minor difference of using a linkedlist  
however after I open the image as I set a loop to add all colors to linkedlist upon the OpenImage acitivity is started

it gives me this error

android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference

Comment: @user1808592 It seems that `iv.getDrawable()` returns `null`. Does your `ImageView` contain an image and if so how was this image set (background or source) ? If this doesn't work, you can go back to using `getDrawingCache()`

Comment: first of all thank you a lot my friend for taking your time to help me 
secondly
I use setbackground I open an image from gallery to imageview and use this code and ask it to run straight after the image is opened in OnActivityResult

Comment: The code in my answer will get the image that was set using `setImageResource(...)` or `setImageDrawable(....)` methods. To get the background as a `Bitmap` you can replace `((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` with `((BitmapDrawable) iv.getBackground()).getBitmap();` but if the background `Drawable` can't be cast to a `BitmapDrawable` object, this won't work either. The safest will be to use `iv.getDrawingCache()` but like I've said, this can get you more then the image.

Comment: seems to be working just fine with .getbackground

You are a live saver my friend

Thank you

Comment: @user1808592 Ok, I'm glad this helped, good look. Don't forget to mark your question as answered.